# Recreating a remote branch at a previous SHA

Tags: git

A team is working from a remote repo using git.

A couple of pushes are made to origin master that are unwanted and are non trivial to revert.

Given that no-one has pulled from the remote since the problematic pushes, can I just do the following without ill effect?

```
git checkout master && 
git reset --hard <green-sha> && 
git push origin :master && 
git push origin master
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why those commits are non-trivial to revert? If you can make a hard reset, reverting should be just as easy. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: As I understand it a revert would basically create mirror image commits to undo them. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it creates inverse commits.

Comment: There are two commits to revert. The first is a merge. Which order should I revert them in?

Comment: You revert in reverse. I don't think the merge should cause problems in principle. Not 100%sure though. But in case of a problem you can always reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `push -f`  to clean the remote and then others should `git fetch` and then `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: Force pushing is unfortunately disabled on the repo. Sorry, I should have made that clear.

Comment: @Ben Removing a branch and force pushing are conceptually pretty similar. I'm pretty sure you won't be able to push what you propose in your question.

Comment: @musiKk You are correct. I get You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the current branch, with or without a warning message. Can I set this config variable from my local shell?

Comment: @Ben This depends on the software you use on the server side. I use gitolite where configuration is done in a special git repository the repository admin needs access to. If you can change those settings, you might as well temporarily enable force push (receive.denyNonFastForwards).